# Identify Tag for detached HEAD

Tags: libgit2

How can I identify the reference name for a detached HEAD in a repo where HEAD points to a Tag?

I'm using git_repository_head() and I noticed that in this state the returned reference is not a tag even tho technically it "is" (`git status` shows `HEAD detached at v1.0.0-alpha.7` for example).

I also noticed that the OID of the head reference doesn't match any of the tags OIDs so I guess there's some indirection?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by looping over all tags (which gives oid and name) and then for each OID getting the tag object. After that I had to peel the tag object into the commit and get the OID of that. If the OID matched head, I got the tag reference.

I'm not sure if this is the only way, it seems like scratching your head by wrapping your arm around from the behind.